# -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:] cellForRowAtIndexPath: crashes when trying to access arrays objectAtIndex:indexPath.row

Tags: uitableview, ios6, xcode4.5

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa84a800'
```

I am loading in data to a `UITableView`, from a custom `UITableViewCell` (**own class and nib**). It works great, Until i try to access the `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` for some arrays.

I'll post my code first, It will probably be easier for you to understand what I mean then.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
if (managedObjectContext==nil) {
    MFAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MFAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

}

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Last" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
}

// Set self's events array to the mutable array, then clean up.
[self setFinal:mutableFetchResults];
lastdisarr=[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"lastdis"];
lastcalarr=[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"lastcal"];
lasttimearr=[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"lasttime"];
date=[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"lastspeed"];
lasticonarr=[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"iconwe"];
NSLog(@"LAst DISTANCE %@",lasticonarr);

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
Cell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];

    cell=self.custom;
}

// Set up the cell...

cell.distance.text=[lastdisarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.timelab.text=[lasttimearr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.callab.text=[lastcalarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.date.text=[date objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//cell.wether.image=[lasticonarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


NSMutableArray *ar=[lasticonarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@",ar);
```

**//problem is here**

**//i want to show image in custom cell & get path from core data....path is getting but image not show on cell**

```
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSLog(@"%@",url1);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[ar description]];


NSLog(@"%@",data);

return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two option:

1: you haven't retained your value;

```
lastdisarr  = [[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"lastdis"] retain];
lastcalarr  = [[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"lastcal"] retain];
lasttimearr = [[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"lasttime"] retain];
```

2: `[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"lastdis"]` is an `NSString`, and not an `NSArray`, as expected.